# if else condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with cols

```
start   end strand  
3   90290834    90290905    +
3   90290834    90291149    +
3   90291019    90291149    +
3   90291239    90291381    +
5   33977824    33984550    -
5   33983577    33984550    -
5   33984631    33986386    -
```

what i am trying to do is add new columns(5ss and 3ss)based on the strand column

```
f = pd.read_clipboard()
f
def addcolumns(row):
    if row['strand'] == "+":
        row["5ss"] == row["start"]
        row["3ss"] == row["end"]

    else:
        row["5ss"] == row["end"]
        row["3ss"] == row["start"]
    return row

f = f.apply(addcolumns, axis=1)
KeyError: ('5ss', u'occurred at index 0')
```

which part of the code is wrong? or there is an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.apply()` I'd suggest using [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where) instead:

```
df.loc[:, '5ss'] = np.where(f.strand == '+', f.start, f.end)
df.loc[:, '3ss'] = np.where(f.strand == '+', f.end, f.start)
```

`np.where()` creates a new object based on three arguments

- A logical condition (in this case `f.strand == '+'`)
- A value to take when the condition is true
- A value to take when the condition is false

Using `apply()` with `axis=1` applies the function to each column.  So even though you've named the variable `row`, it's actually iterating over columns.  You could leave out the `axis` argument or specify `axis=0` to apply the function to the rows.  But given what you're trying to do, it would be simpler to use `np.where()`, which allows you to specify some conditional logic for column assignment.

Comment: could you please walk me through the code its interesting, it worked as desired.

Comment: @sbradbio sure, added a little explanation.